# Replacing negative numbers with zero in a matrix

Tags: r

So today I was coding up something where I wanted to replace all negative values in a matrix with 0. Call this matrix B. Well this was no problem, I just wrote

```
B[which(B<0)]=0
```

But then just because I was curious I was wondering, what if we got rid of the which and wrote

```
B[B<0]=0
```

and to my surprise this also gave the same answer. If I would have looked up this question on Stack Overflow the second answer is pretty standard (and there are even more complicated faster methods), but my question is: are the two methods above actually the same? B<0 returns a Boolean matrix. Which method is faster and why?

Comment: Which method works best depends on the situation. For example, if you have a large data frame from which you select only a few rows, then using `which` is often faster. I assume this is because directly pulling those rows out of the parent object is more efficient than checking every row to see whether it meets the condition.

Comment: This was the type of answer I was looking for! I was suspecting that it wasn't as simple as Tyler suggested based on my speed test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the issue of speed, there doesn't appear to be a big difference in tests I tried. For example,

```
B=.5-matrix(runif(10000),100,100) 

start = Sys.time()  
replicate(50000,B[B<0])
speed = Sys.time () - start
```

25.85 seconds

```
start = Sys.time()  
replicate(50000,B[which(B<0)])
speed = Sys.time () - start
```

25.91 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can index with a logical vector. It's explained here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Index-vectors

Comment: @VictorK. I have unaccepted this answer because it does not talk about speed at all, which was the crux of the question. Feel free to edit your answer accordingly.